# JavaScript Closure Callback Itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, closures

Here is the closure I wrote:

```
var slider = (function(){
    var count = 3;
    return function(){
        if (count>0) {
            $("#message").html("<h1>"+count+"</h1>");
            count--;
            $("#message").removeClass("animated zoomIn");
            $("#message").addClass("animated zoomIn");
            $("#message").one("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend",  function(){
                return slider();
            }());   
        } else{
            showCube();
        }
    }()
});
```

This closure gets executed by a jquery plugin:

```
$("#fishes").addClass("animated slideOutLeft").one("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", slider());
```

However, the callback is not getting executed. Can someone guide me in the correct direction please?

Comment: Why should he use `slider`? He expects `slider()` to return a handler that `one` wants. The problem is the `()` inside the `return`, in the next-to-last line.

Comment: Nope. It did not work. I tried changing the slider.
I am wondering why the call back is failing to get attached to the dom element.

Comment: If that helps,
one('','') itself is a handler to a jquery plugin.
i.e one gets triggered once the animation effect on the dom element ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I read it, you want `slider()` to return a closure you can use for `one`. However - it doesn't, as your code suffers from the premature execution syndrome.

Your `slider` function creates a closure, then *immediately executes it*, then returns the result of that execution. Since the inner closure has no `return` statements, the value returned from `slider()` is `undefined`, and `one` doesn't get any handler to attach.

Solution: remove the `()` from the second-to-last line. That should make `slider()` return a closure rather than its result.

**EDIT:** Your `function() { return slider(); }()` is equivalent to `slider()`, which constructs a new closure where `count` is `3`. Replace it with `arguments.callee`, to provide the same closure that is executing right now.

```js
var slider = (function(){
    var count = 3;
    return function(){
        if (count>0) {
            $("#message").html("<h1>"+count+"</h1>");
            count--;
            $("#message").one("click", arguments.callee);   
        } else{
            alert("The End");
        }
    }
});
$('#message').one('click', slider());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message">Click me!</div>
```

Or, you can name it, so you can reference it directly:

```js
var slider = (function(){
    var count = 3;
    return function sliderClosure(){
        if (count>0) {
            $("#message").html("<h1>"+count+"</h1>");
            count--;
            $("#message").one("click", sliderClosure);   
        } else{
            alert("The End");
        }
    }
});
$('#message').one('click', slider());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message">Click me!</div>
```

Comment: That did not work either. I understood the premature execution syndrome. Can you throw more light on why the self invoking part should be truncated?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I thought that's exactly what I explained.

Comment: I tested for the count value. It came down to 2. But then it did not go into one more loop.
i.e the callback did not get binded to the dom again.

Comment: Why would it get bound to the DOM again? You only execute `.one` once, and it's not in any loop that I can see. In fact, the `return slider()` is useless, as it will construct a closure then return it - but the caller doesn't care about the return value, so it is discarded. If you want to loop it, replace it with another call to `.one`.

Comment: The loop lies within the closure.
("#message") contents are changed and a new event is bind to the new content. The exit condition for the loop is when counter < 0
That is where the closure is failing.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see the internal `.one` call. However, I can't see that failing as you say; I'd expect it to go into an infinite loop, since you construct another closure that again has `count` at `3`...

Comment: Exactly! Can you please help me how can I construct the next closure with one value less?
Also, when I removed all inner call backs retaining only:
$("#message").one("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend", 
    slider()
   );
The count works good. However, the animation doesn't appear!

Comment: Added the example code; replaced animationend with click since the question does not include any animation code.

Comment: It kind of worked. But the code never enters the else condition. I am wondering why! Do you have any guess?

Comment: The code in my example definitely does enter the `else` condition, as you can see by running it on this very page. Without additional data, I don't know what you did, only what I did - and that demonstrably works.

Comment: I got the problem.
my .one() is a jquery plugin handler. Unlike click, it functionality is obscure for me too.
That particular event handler [animation end event handler] is failing to update count properly. But your answer is correct. Thank you :)

Comment: Got it resolved! It is a normal closure. But since, .one event is used, I had to remove the dom element and re add it inorder for the closure to act correct. 
Thanks a lot the issue is resolved now!